# Sort algorithm that sorts according to original index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Do any of the `sort algorithms` sort a given array of integers such that in case `a[i]=a[j]`, it is considered that `a[i]>a[j]` if `i>j`?

Comment: The one you write that does it such a way does.

Comment: Yes. You want a so-called stable sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for **stable** sorting algorithms. Stable sorting algorithms maintain the relative order of records with equal keys (i.e. values).
Concept explanation -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Algorithms which are stable - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Sorting algorithms defines the general steps to sort the input. Such edge cases are handled by actual implementation depending on the requirement of the user.